# NetBeans Servlet MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED

The problem lay with the parameter names.

I am trying to create a basic login servlet that will check the login details of employees.

However my servlet doesn't seem to be interacting with the data base and always returns me to the "tryagain.jsp".
What am I doing wrong?
I am using glassfish and netbeans.
I have j/connector driver in the library files as well.

THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED

The problem lay with the parameter names.

Here is the code.

```
package loginServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author asus
 */
public class Login1 extends HttpServlet {


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/northwind";
       String uname=request.getParameter("username");
String passwd=request.getParameter("userPass");
        try {
            // load the driver class
            Class.forName(DRIVER);

            // establish connection to database                              
            conn =
                    DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "jonh86", "ADMIN");
            System.out.println("Connected....");
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from userdata where user_name = ? and password = ?");
            ps.setString(1, uname);
            ps.setString(2, passwd);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("WelcomeServlet");
            rd.forward(request, response);

//out.println(rs.getString(2));
            } else {
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("tryagain.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
            }
        } 


        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Please condense to only relevant part of the code

Comment: What is the `System.out.println(e);` exception print? post it?

Comment: I'm not getting an error it isn't checking the details. It always redirects me to the welcome page. This code worked on a normal java file. Could the problem be with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reason yourself with some proper error checking. There are heaps of reasons why it could fail.

```
// establish connection to database                              
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "jonh86", "ADMIN");
            if(conn == null) System.out.println("Could not Connect");
            System.out.println("Connected...."); //--this code is misleading
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from userdata where user_name = ? and password = ?");
            ps.setString(1, uname);
            ps.setString(2, passwd);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Also, you should be catching SQLExceptions and printing them:

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
}
```

Comment: I added your code but it didn't print could not connect or connected...  It just redirects to the try again page every time.

Comment: I took your advice and established that the problem lay in the parameter names. My god 2 hours wasted on an uncapped letter. Ah the joys of learning to program.

Comment: yes, and if you put error handling and learn to read exceptions then the 2 hours "wasted" becomes 1 hour, then 30 minutes etc. etc. as you get more experienced.